# Document Library Template: The language is not supported on the server

Tags: wss-3.0, site-template, error, language

We have created a document library template to facilitate the rapid deployment of multiple document libraries with identical structure. The template has been created within the same site and the same collection as where it will be deployed, but when we try to deploy it we get an error stating "The language is not supported on the server". I don't understand why the template wouldn't match the language of the site it was created in. Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Unfortunately I'm limited in a corporate environment, so I can't access the central admin or remote into the farm.

Comment: I spoke with one one the techs at our corporate host and it appears to be an issue deep within the farm. Templates aren't deploying anywhere across the corporation; I guess it's not my code after all. I'll update if we learn what it was in case anyone else runs into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are deploying as a feature?  If so, you will also need to set the Core resource file to point to the default language resource by adding the following attribute to your feature.xml file:

DefaultResourceFile="core"

Answer (score 1):

What language is the installation? What language packs are deployed? What is your sharepoint development language? Check the LCID of our feature.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same error. when trying to create a document library programmatically based on a document library template. Did you solve the issue? Thx